# wildcard character `* ` can't match some string?

Tags: linux, bash

```
ls  -al  .functions*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 471040 Mar  2 10:01 .functions.php.swo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 438272 Mar  2 09:57 .functions.php.swp
```

`*` can match `.php.swo` and `.php.swp`
Why `*` can't match `.functions.php` ?

```
ls  -al  *.swo
ls: cannot access '*.swo': No such file or directory
ls  -al  *swo
ls: cannot access '*swo': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files which begin with a dot are hidden from file listings by default. The easiest way to match those kind of files would be to put a dot in the beginning of the expression. However, this will onyl match files starting with `.`.

```
ls  -al  .*.swo
```

The alternative is to set the `dotglob` before running the command, then files starting with `.` will be included.

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Add it to your `~/.bashrc` to set it by default.

Note that **setting `dotglob` can lead to uninteded results** when using the bash shell, since both `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory) will appear when using `*`. With `dotglob` set, **never** try to use `rm -R *`.

Comment: Warning: dotglob can have unexpected consequences, since `*` will include `.` (the current directory) and `..` (the parent of the current directory). Try setting dotglob, then doing `ls *`. Do *not* try `rm -R *`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Added the warning to the answer so it is not lost/removed.

Comment: please note that other shells like `zsh` actually implement dotglob in a way that matches neither `.` nor `..` -- a much more useful behavior in my opinion

Comment: @Shaido Perhaps **bold** would be a good idea. This is a very unexpected and dangerous feature, and I know people who always use `-f`.

Comment: FYI, these patterns are *not* regular expressions. They're called either globs or wildcards.

Answer (score 11):

As an **extension** to Shaido's answer I'd like to give some explanation why the `-a` option will not work here:

The `ls` command does **not** process wildcards. The command line interpreter does this step:

If you type the command line "`mycommand *.c`" the command line interpreter will first replace the wildcard string "`*.c`" by the list of matching files and then execute the resulting command line:

```
mycommand a.c file.c test.c
```

The command line interpreter works the same way for all commands so it cannot know that `-a` means "including hidden files" in the case the `ls` command (while `-a` has a totally different meaning for other commands)...